# How to resolve Conflicting types for 'sprintf'?

Tags: c++, objective-c, osx-lion, xcode4.5, stdio

I am using **stdio.h** file in my project.

when compile time from Xcode i used

```
 Comipler for C/C++/Objective-C: LLVM GCC 4.2
```

During compile time getting **Conflicting types for 'sprintf'** error.This is working fine in Mac OS 10.6.8 & Xcode 3.2.3 but in Mac OS 10.7.4 & Xcode 4.5 getting error? please help me?

this is code in Mac OS X 10.7.4

```
 __BEGIN_DECLS
 int     fseeko(FILE *, off_t, int);
 off_t   ftello(FILE *);
 __END_DECLS
#endif /* __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= 200112L */

#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= 200112L || defined(_C99_SOURCE) || defined(__cplusplus)
__BEGIN_DECLS
 int     snprintf(char * __restrict, size_t, const char * __restrict, ...) __printflike(3,   4);
 int     vfscanf(FILE * __restrict, const char * __restrict, va_list) __scanflike(2, 0);
int  vscanf(const char * __restrict, va_list) __scanflike(1, 0);
int  vsnprintf(char * __restrict, size_t, const char * __restrict, va_list) __printflike(3, 0);
int  vsscanf(const char * __restrict, const char * __restrict, va_list) __scanflike(2, 0);
__END_DECLS
#endif /* __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= 200112L || defined(_C99_SOURCE) || defined(__cplusplus) */
```

Comment: Can you post the code that causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check whether the format pattern and the arguments of `sprintf` and similar functions match was recently added to the compilers of XCode 4.4 (if I'm not mistaken). It's a valuable check that highlights problems in your code that went unnoticed with earlier version.

In my case, the compiler was always right. So you better fix the format pattern or convert the corresponding argument.

*If you post the specific code, we can give your more specific advice.*